# Powerpoint Preview and Thumbnail

Tags: java, powerpoint, preview, file-conversion

We are providing a thumbnail & preview functionality for rich powerpoint documents on our Java based site.
Currently, we are using [iSpringConverter](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/free_powerpoint_to_flash_converter.html) tool for converting the powerpoint documents to swf file.
The tool is licensed and windows based, and allows interaction through java.
This swf file is then launched on the client side as popups.

Can anyone suggest any other tools/frameworks/options/approaches used for implementing
 - Generation of thumbnails and preview for powerpoints
 - Viewers used, in case the preview is generated in some formats.

Any more ideas/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try SWFTOOLS, it works very well :) 
You can make calls to it running command lines (using Process class).

I dont know if it transparently make thumbnails and etc... but I think you can done it by yourself using it.

hope it helps.

http://www.swftools.org/

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Aspose.Slides for Java](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.slides-for-java/index.html) to [create thumbnails of the PowerPoint slides in your Java application](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.slides-for-java/creating-slide-thumbnail-image.html). You can then show those images as a preview using any image control. This component doesn't require MS Office/Open Office etc. to be installed on your development or deployment machines for processing PowerPoint files. The API is quite simple and provides detailed documentation and help. Please see if this might help in your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.